# .Click on an a tag does not work

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to navigate into a web page automatically with VBA to scrape some values from different product ID's. The problem is that when I get to this intermediate page: http://www.siicex-caaarem.org.mx/Bases/TIGIE2007.nsf/4caa80bd19d9258006256b050078593c/$searchForm?SearchView (search for code 11081201, for example), where I'm supposed to click on the only "a" tag there, the program keeps crashing with

> Object variable or With block variable not set

on the line that should click on the element:

```
objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
```

I have been using similar working lines of code for the same purpose on different pages (ussualy with a for each loop, which doesnt work here either), so I'm unsure why it doesn't work here. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this was adding `DoEvents` before the line that clicks on the element.